# iTunes Connect asking for Apple Watch screens when the app is iOS only

Tags: app-store-connect, watchos

I recently noticed itunes connect is asking me to include apple watch screens.

[image]

But I never included any watchos capabilities on xcode as a deployment target or target dependencies.

Is there anytithing I am missing in terms of deployment configuration on xcode or itunes connect?

Or this is just another bug?

Comment: The option to upload them is always shown in iTunes Connect, similar to iPad screenshots even if the app is for iPhones only. Just ignore it and don't upload Apple Watch screenshots.
P.S. There won't change anything in iTunes Connect, if you change your build settings.

Comment: I reported a bug informing Apple I was getting an error when trying to change my primary localisation. They said that was because I haven’t uploaded any screens for WatchOS. If it is the way you say it is then there is another bug with iTunes Connect as it shouldn’t make the screens mandatory for switching the localisation.

Comment: They probably meant "normal"/iPhone screenshots. It's a known issue that you cannot switch the primary localisation, without adding screenshots. Just search here at stackoverflow.

Comment: I already had screens for iOS in place for each localisation, independently. And was still not able to switch. I reported a bug and they were clear, I needed screens for WatchOS to be able to switch. So I added a couple of fake WatchOS screens and it worked. Just deleted the screens afterwards. So another bug… I won’t even bother reporting another bug as this new iTunesConnect things seems all messed up.

Comment: In iTunes Connect page about build I found some information about identifier like "000000.myApp.watchkitapp"... So I didn't understand where it was from. For hours I was looking this identifier and finally I just turn off "automatically manage signing". I made and upload a new build to itunes connect and looked at new build there and saw that identifier like "000000.myApp.watchkitapp" disappear.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that your Project has not any relation to Watchkit and WatchOS:

1) Find eventual `import WK...` lines and remove them

2) Go to Project file -> iOS app target -> Build Phases tab -> `Target Dependencies` and check whether you have not *WatchKit extension* in the list

3) Check Build Phases -> `Embed App Extensions/Binaries` - check whether *WatchKit extension* is not included.