# iTunes Connect asking for 6.5-inch and Apple Watch screenshots

Tags: app-store-connect, screenshot

I'm releasing a new iOS app version in itunesconnect, but it asks me to upload 6.5-inch and Apple Watch screenshots and don't allow me to submit app for review.

Plus, i was able to release iOS app without 6.5-inch screenshots. Why does it need 6.5-inch now?

I checked from [iTunes Connect asking for Apple Watch screens when the app is iOS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383576/itunes-connect-asking-for-apple-watch-screens-when-the-app-is-ios-only) and confirmed did not add any dependencies for watchkit or anything related to that.

I expect to release iOS app in itunesconnect without 6.5-inch and Apple Watch screenshots, but itunesconnect says there's an error and require me to upload both of the type of the screenshots, which I don't have at the moment

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem too. I don't know who downvoted this but this is very relevant. I spent some time trying to find dependencies related to watchkit because apple made me think I was building an app for the Apple Watch, then I found this post. Thank you for asking this and saving me the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Apple and it seems like 6.5-inch display screenshots is the latest requirement. It works after adding the screenshots for that display. It seems like Apple Watch screenshots is a false error. It still works as long as 6.5-inch screenshot is added.